# Map two columns of a filtered second table to one Collection member

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

## Summary

I wonder whether it is possible to map the following query to a member of entity class `Bar`:

```
Select f.columnA, f.columnB From Foo f Where f.barId = '[someDynamicBarId]';
```

**Note:** I can't change the schema (e.g. to add a mapping table).

## Background

I have the classes `Bar` and `Foo` and I want to add a `Map<String, BigDecimal>` or `List<Object[]>` to `Bar` from a very big table `Foo` (*10m* entries) for entries containing `Bar.barId = '[barId]'` only.

I display *50* `Bar` elements in a lazy loaded `dataTable` but my current solution to get `columnA` and `columnB` from `Foo` is even for these *50* entries very slow (*80* seconds):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "barId")
private List<Foo> fooList; // fooList.size() == 500
```

This should be replaced by

```
private Map<String, BigDecimal> fooMap;
```

or

```
private List<Object[]> fooList; // object { columnA, columnB }
```

I tried with `@ElementCollection` and `@OneToMany` in connection with Hibernate's `@Where` or `@WhereJoinTable`. The problem is that I could not define a variable in these queries. `@Formula` is also not working as it is designed to return one row only.

## Structure

The classes are:

```
class Bar {

   @Id
   private String barId;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "barId")
   private List<Foo> fooList;

   ...
}


class Foo {

   @Id
   private String fooId;

   private String columnA; // not unique

   private BigDecimal columnB; // not unique

   private String barId; // not unique

   ...
}
```

`columnA` is unique for every `barId`:

```
barId  columnA
---------------
 b01    cA01
 b01    cA02
 b01    cB01

 b02    cA01
 b02    cA02
 b02    cB01
```

## Outcome

I want to have `Bar` like this:

```
class Bar {

   @Id
   private String barId;

   @ElementCollection
   @MapKeyColumn(name = "columnA") // ?
   @Column(name = "columnB") // ?
   // ? @Filter('barId = :barId')
   // ? @Formula('Select f.columnA, f.columnB From Foo f Where f.barId = barId')
   // ? @Where('barId = :barId')
   private Map<String, BigDecimal> fooMap;

   ...
}
```

Actually, my problem would be solved if I could get the combination of (`barId`,) `columnA` and `columnB` in a reasonable time. Does not have to be implemented like I described above. The tables are indexed on requested columns in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gna, I just found a solution.

```
class Bar {

  @Id
  private String barId;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = BigDecimal.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
  @JoinTable(name="Foo", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "barId"))
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "columnA")
  @Column(name = "columnB")
  private Map<String, BigDecimal> fooMap;

  ...
}
```

<strike>The main problem remains: It is very slow (*57* seconds). Any suggestions to improve the speed?</strike>

**Edit:** Recreating the indexes in the database solved the problem. It takes now less than a second to get the full table.